# PHP Objects broken, $this is undefined

Tags: php

The code:

```php
<?php

class My_Test{

    public $exists = 'yah';

    public function test(){
            return $this->exists;
    }

}

$test = new My_Test;
echo $test->test();
```

produces the following error intermittently (every other page request on average) on two servers:

```
( ! ) Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in test.php on line 8
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0003  636392  {main}( )   ../test.php:0
2   0.0003  636840  My_Test->test( )    ../test.php:14
```

where line 10 is `return $this->exists;

Please note this is not an untested example, it is the full code that produces the error. I'm aware the code is valid but it doesn't work in two environments.

I'm really not sure why! One server is running PHP 5.3.3 (fedora), the other PHP 5.3.2 (ubuntu). I've tried rebooting the servers too. They don't share anything, although they are on the same network.

Anyone got any tips for debugging?

Comment: That's odd, [it works for me](http://codepad.viper-7.com/tzWviF)

Comment: Works fine for me http://codepad.viper-7.com/teAxDr

Comment: Is there more to the error other than the notice?  You mentioned $this being undefined in the title, is that an error you are receiving?

Comment: http://ideone.com/k6shq - works fine for me as well.

Comment: I assume this is a very simplified code snippet because the code works from the CLI interface. The only thinkg I could think of is that you instance the class without invoking the constructor.

Comment: No, this is the code that is failing. I simplified it from the code that originally failed, but this test code also fails.

Comment: is php.ini on both boxes the same? Might there be any issue with extensions installed? I could guess the problem might be traced to an OpCode cacher or anything like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As people before stated the code looks fine and should not cause any errors.

Therefore I guess it is related to an error of the php engine itself:

*How did you install PHP?*

- Did you compile the sourcecode yourself? Have ./configure or make logged any warnings or error messages while executing?
- Have you installed PHP by use of a package manager? (I guess everything should be fine then).

*How did you configure PHP?*

- Have you made any changes to php.ini like changing memory limit, paths, etc. ?
- Have you installed any extension that might cause issues? My experience says often opcode caches (e.g. APC) can cause errors that cannot be easily explained. Also debuggers or other extensions may cause interferences.

*Do you have any (additional) error messages in your HTTP-Daemon-Log?*

- Sometimes additional errors can be found in the error.log file in case the server is configured to do so (e.g. unexpected termination of script or similar).

Comment: Thanks GeneSys, it was a problem with php, it was seg faulting in a completely different application but whenever the erroneous script ran, it managed to bork any other PHP that ran through apache until apache was restarted.

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing wrong with your test code.  It runs without issue on PHP 5.3.3.  You've probably lost the cause of the issue when converting your "real" code into test code to post on here.

Comment: Not true, this IS the code I am using and that is producing the error. I know that this code is valid, the point of the question (which I will try to rephrase), is why are two of my environments failing with this **valid** code?

Comment: @user1098407:  Considering that your pasted error and call stack dump point to line numbers that don't match the code that you've pasted, I find this highly unlikely.

Comment: I took out the line: echo phpversion() . PHP_EOL; It was on line 3, it wasn't causing the error.. trust me, I know the code shouldn't error, but it is. The code does work on other boxes,just not these two.

Comment: @awoods: Your original call stack referenced line 16 (`../test.php:16`, which you've now edited to read 14 instead) and you've only pasted 13 lines of code.  Unless your `phpversion()` call took up 3 lines for some reason, you're omitting other code, as well.  If you want real help, please paste the _actual_ code that you're testing.  Otherwise, no one can help you.

Comment: That was the code, I've traced it to a segmentation fault, but that WAS the code.. I can't believe I have to even justify it. Ridiculous.

Comment: @awoods:  PHP segfaulted and then spit out a notice?  Hmmm :-p  Magic!

Comment: the segfault was in another application, but any subsequent request to any PHP file through apache would fail with notices like (and including) the one I pasted. It was stupid not to check the error logs first, but it was odd that it was happening across multiple servers. It turns out that both servers run the app causing the seg fault, even across different php versions. Upgrading from 5.3.2/3 to 5.3.8 on both servers fixed it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5871/discussion-between-awoods-and-drrcknlsn)

Answer (score 0):

The code appears to work as is, but I've never seen an object instantiated without the parens.

```
$test = new My_Test;

// Should be

$test = new My_Test();
```

You could also implement some logging:

```
public function test()
{
    // Can edit this to use instanceof or getclass for further testing
    if (!is_object($this)) {
        error_log(serialize($this));
    }

    return $this->exists;
}
```

Comment: In fact this is (correct) PHP code style. You may instantiate an object even without braces, see http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php

Comment: @GeneSys: What do you mean 'correct'? Upon delving into several of the links spawned by your link, all the examples show the parens.

Comment: Correct in terms of: It is semantically and lexically correct to instantiate an object by use of the default constructor (or user-defined constructor with no parameters) without specifing the parantesis after the class name. The first code example on http://at2.php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php says on line 10: `$bar = new foo;`

Comment: @GeneSys: I am following up purely for the sake of learning. What you are telling me means that myself and several colleagues are not following the 'correct' syntax for instantiating objects. Granted it's basically preference, but if it's industry standard to leave off the parents (if no args) then that's good to know. I saw the example on line 10, did you see the other 10+ examples on the other links where they instantiated with parens?

Comment: You are also following the correct syntax if you put paranthesis after the class name when instantiating objects. What is "correct" here is only what the coding guidelines tell you to do: E.g. Kohana Framework says: *When creating an instance of a class, don't use parentheses if you're not passing something on to the constructor* (http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/kohana/conventions#classes). If your coding guidelines tell you to put paranthesis after it that's also fine ;)

Comment: @GeneSys: Ahhh thanks for the example, that's just what I was looking for. Good insight.